# Mounting disk automatically on terminal and persist across users and restarts

Tags: command-line, mount, hard-drive, persistence

On the GUI, we can click on the `File > Devices > HDD-Name` to automatically mount the disks to `/media/`.

I could mount them one by one manually, i.e. https://superuser.com/questions/467170/how-do-i-mount-internal-hdds-in-ubuntu-via-the-command-line

But **is there a way to do the same automatically on the command line?**

Also, **how can these mounted drive persists after I restart the machine or across users?**. E.g. if the way to do it automatically is a single command, I can put it in `.bashrc` to mount them automatically whenever I log on to the user.

Comment: Put mount command into /etc/bash.bashrc and mount in a shared directory between user to let all user to access that partition.

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is for mounting devices permanently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mount a device at boot and have it visible in terminal you need to edit /etc/fstab

You can find explanation on how to edit and examples at this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab